# jaxrs.ResteasyClient download file

Tags: client, resteasy

Request a webAPI that gives me a ZIP file. Now my question: 
How to download that file with `jaxrs.ResteasyClient`. Here is what I have but it does not work for me.

```
// In
Reader reader = client.target(url).request().get().readEntity(Reader.class);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

// Out
File out = new File("C:\\tmp\\test.zip");
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(out);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
String s = null;

while (true) {
  s = bufferedReader.readLine();

  if (s == null) {
    break;
  }

  bufferedWriter.write(s);
}

bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
bufferedReader.close();
```

I have no idea if this makes sense, but I do not find any good documentation about reading a file instead of a bean object.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by not using `jaxrs.ResteasyClient`. Apache `HTTPClient` was my friend!

```
private void getFileByURL(String url, String target) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
  HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom().build();
  CloseableHttpClient client = builder.build();

  HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(new URI(url)));
  BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
  BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(target)));
  int inByte;
  while ((inByte = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
    bufferedOutputStream.write(inByte);
  }
  bufferedInputStream.close();
  bufferedOutputStream.close();
  EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
```